# Esconder teclado ao escolher um texto no AutoComplete

Tags: android, app, teclado, autocompletar

Estou utilizando elementos do tipo **AutoComplete** no projeto, para que quando o usuário digite parte do texto que busca, apresenta as opções sugeridas para o mesmo.

Para isso, estou utilizando o seguinte trecho:

```
private void arrayAutoComplete() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, produto);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.editProduto);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private static final String[] produto = new String[]{
        "Skol beats sensations", "Brahma", "Skol litrão", "Heinekein", "Skol 350 ml"
};
```

Quero saber, como faço para esconder o teclado do smartphone quando o usuário selecione um dos textos sugeridos.

Answer (score 1):

Para executar uma ação ao selecionar um item, é utilizado o *listener* [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). Então você pode tentar algo assim:

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
});
```